# Using diff. stylesheets with diff. pages in Wordpress HTML5Blank template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, templates

I am making a site on Wordpress and plugging in my custom html and css to the HTML5Blank template.  The css file is enqueued using WordPress functions into wp_head... I have tried inserting a conditional php if statement into head and it has no effect because

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

is still being called.  Removing this and keeping the conditional statement

```
 <?php if( is_home() ) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/front-style.css" />
<?php } else { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( '/style.css' ); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

still doesn't fix it.  I want my homepage to call a different css file than the rest of the website. I'll only need potentially 2 css files and have already made another one called frontstyle.css in the same directory as the original css file.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: have also been trying this but it isn't working either but actually seems the most promising.

```
 ?php if( is_home() ) { ?>
        <?php get_header(); ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <?php get_header( 'other' ); ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

with files header.php and header-other.php respectively.  All I really need to change is the header.  I plugged this into the page template and didn't get the response I needed but it did change a bit.

Comment: Have you tried writing a conditional into the functions.php?

Comment: I tried and weird glitches started happening unrelated to my code involving a debug function.  It's probably something I did but it was nowhere near my inserted code.

Comment: Do you really need more than one CSS file? You know that you can style different pages purely from CSS declarations, using the body classes right? For example, the front page uses the class `body.home`

Comment: Brilliant.  That solved it!